# Difference between normal class and class with injection

Tags: java, class, dependency-injection, guice

Consider 2 classes, Student and Subject.

**Case 1 :**

```
class Student
{
   private final Subject subject;

   Student (final Subject subject)
   {
     this.subject = subject;
   }
   //do something
}
```

**Case 2 :**

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

class Student
{
   private final Subject subject;

   @Inject
   Student (final Subject subject)
   {
     this.subject = subject;
   }
   //do something
}
```

**Can someone explain the difference between these two cases, and when each case is used?**

Comment: Note 100% sure, but: First, if you're not using the correct framework, there's no difference.  The annotation does nothing by itself.  If you are using a correct framework, such as Spring, then some code will be automatically created for you.  C.f. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire

Comment: @markspace: almost correct. It's correct that the annotation does nothing on its own. But Spring doesn't (by default) generate source code for you. Instead it uses that information at runtime to instantiate objects directly based on it and other annotations/configurations. Note that *other* DI frameworks **do** indeed generate source code, a prime example is Dagger.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Interesting.  I thought all the big JEE frameworks used byte code generation / code weaving these days.  So Spring still uses reflection, at least for some features?  Didn't know that.

Comment: I'll throw out a third answer: `javac` (the Java compiler) now contains an annotation processor, which is used to alter classes statically before a program is run, which might also be used to generate code or include additional support classes at compile time.  So there's inspection at runtime, byte code weaving during a class loading at runtime, and static code generation before any code is run, in addition to "ignore it and do nothing" which is also a possibility.

Comment: @markspace: annotation processing *can not* actually alter any classes. It can *only* generate additional code.  That is why projects like Lombok (which very much modifies the class on which the annotations are) actually has to build their own tooling which is not the same as normal annotation processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there is no difference in the behavior of the class (methods are the same and contain the same code) and the information that this class maintains (data fields are the same).

But this class doesn't "live" in vacuum, probably its a part of an application that contains many other classes, and you have somehow to manage the classes, dependencies between them, and so forth. So here comes the difference:

The difference is how do you organize the application, more precisely who "Manages" this class, read, who creates it (calls `new Student`) and who is responsible for "figuring out" where to "get" the instance of class Subject that the object of type Student obviously must be supplied with in order to get instantiated properly.

So there are many ways to manage your code in this sense:

You can do everything by yourself:

```
main() {
Subject subject = new Subject()
Student student = new Student(subject)

}
```

Now if there are say 1000 classes, you'll have to maintain 1000 lines of code to create all these objects. Although In this case, it might still seem doable, because objects are created together, but sometimes the real applications can be much more complicated than that, the dependency resolution may also become much more complicated.

Hence there were created DI containers like Guice, Spring and so forth:

They can figure out by themselves how to instantiate the classes, analyze the class's structure to figure out the dependencies and bottom line create the classes for your.
To provide the "hints" to these containers you can use annotations like `@Inject` but all-in-all, you manage the application in a different way:

- your classes get created by the dependency injection container
- you may provide hints to the container that will "help" it to create a class, by using these hints the DI container is able to resolve the actual way of instantiation (how to call new by reflection, which constructor to call, which parameters to pass, in which order, etc).
- As a consequence you don't maintain code like `new Student, new Subject()`, etc. Dependency injection container does it for you.

Basically its a very broad topic, so for educational purposes I suggest you to find a comprehensive tutorial about this DI topic even before you dive into the particular implementation technicalities (like `@Inject` in Google Guice).